# Timelock and Metamask: We were not able to estimate gas. Write deposit function fails

Tags: metamask, timelock

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Timelock {
  uint public constant duration = 365 days;
  uint public immutable end;
  address payable public immutable owner;

  constructor(address payable _owner) {
    end = block.timestamp + duration;
    owner = _owner; 
  }

  function deposit(address token, uint amount) external {
    IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
  }

  receive() external payable {}

  function withdraw(address token, uint amount) external {
    require(msg.sender == owner, 'only owner');
    require(block.timestamp >= end, 'too early');
    if(token == address(0)) { 
      owner.transfer(amount);
    } else {
      IERC20(token).transfer(owner, amount);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Milk Contract, which I deployed before:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x8384b0ad2044e3b4c43c89c425d3ba4830b16f36

If I want to call the deposit function of Contract TimeLock Metamask says: *We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.* I put the contract address of my deployed Milk Contract and the amount in the function deposit to write them via bscscan. I set also as address payable my Metamask address as owner from which I deployed the contracts, is this correct? or is it the address of milk contract?
This is my migrations js file:

```
//const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
const Timelock = artifacts.require("Timelock");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
 // deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(Timelock,"0xec125D397cdA00f7390c1C6E76d4ca9902357fd3");
};
```

I think the problem is the IERC20 in the deposit function. Why do I need to import IERC20.sol and do I need them? Why I cannot write the function and why Metamask cannot estimade Gas? Any help would be appreciated. below the failed txhash: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x9ff191b4725781dc7174c58bb94fdfc61d4bbc484b04b21f61216ff822acda8f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction reverted because you forgot to approve the `TimeLock` contract (address 0x91492C12C43a5dd018e32EA6b66178eCC71e22BF) to use your `Milk` token: `Milk.allowance(0xec125D39..your_address, 0x91492C..TimeLock_address) = 0`

To do it you need to call `approve(timelock_address, amount)` with the account that you will call deposit. E.g. to make your failed transaction working, you need to call this on `Milk` token contract:

```
approve(0x91492C12C43a5dd018e32EA6b66178eCC71e22BF, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
```

You can do it using the WriteContract button on [BsCscan of Milk Token](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x8384b0ad2044e3b4c43c89c425d3ba4830b16f36#writeContract)

Comment: thank you very much, you are king. How can I withdraw the token again. Metamask says now again cannot esitmad gas. Do I need at withdraw again to call approve?

Comment: According to the code of timelock, to withdraw you have to wait 365 days. `end = block.timestamp + duration;`, it's the time lock. And you must call `withdraw` with the same address that you used to deploy this contract: `require(msg.sender == owner, 'only owner');`.