# I can't transfer web3js forward contract (USDT)

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to write rpc api via web3 with nodejs.
I made ETH transfers somehow, but I couldn't make contract (USDT) transfers in particular.

web3 : I am using version 1.8.1.

Can you send sample code?

```
let tokenAddress = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";
let toAddress = '0x25' 
let fromAddress = '0xA48' 
let privateKey = '0xxxx'
let contractABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./usdt_abi.json", "utf-8"));
let gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    "from": fromAddress,
});
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, tokenAddress);
const tx = {
    from: fromAddress,
    to: tokenAddress,
    gas: gass,
    value: 0,
    data: contract.methods.transferFrom(fromAddress, tokenAddress).encodeABI(),
};
const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
const hash = await sendSignedTransaction(signedTx);

console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the wrong ABI of ERC20. The correct function signature should be either one of the two:

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public;
function transfer(address _to, uint _value)
```

`transfer` is usually used when you are the owner and you have the private key to sign this transaction directly (which is probably the case from your code). You should change the data field to this (assuming you want to send 100 USDT to `toAddress` and the `privateKey` is associated with `fromAddress`:

```js
data: contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, 100 ).encodeABI()
```

`transferFrom` is usually used by smart contract to transfer the approved token on behalf of the user (the user must call `approve` first: [look at my other answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/142161/108141)) If you want to use `transferFrom`, the recipient is not `tokenAddress` and you forgot to state the amount.
You should change the data field to this (assuming you want to send 100 USDT from `fromAddress` to `toAddress` :

```js
data: contract.methods.transferFrom(fromAddress, toAddress, 100 ).encodeABI()
```

Update, based on the comment: you also need to update the [estimated gas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) :

```js
//...
let contractABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./usdt_abi.json", "utf-8"));
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, tokenAddress);
let gas = await contract.methods.transfer(toAddress,100).estimateGas({from: fromAddress});
const tx = {
    from: fromAddress,
    to: tokenAddress,
    gas: gas,
    value: 0,
    data: contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, 100 ).encodeABI(),
};
//...
```

Comment: Also the gas used is for an ether transfer not for a ERC20 transfer.

Comment: oh I missed that, thanks :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please share the sample code for me? I've done a lot of research on this and I'm new. I'm so confused

Comment: and which web3 version should i use?

Comment: the code should work, you need to replace the line from let contractABI =... to const tx = ... with the lines in the last code block. your web3 version should work well

Comment: if there are additional errors you can post it here

Comment: thank you for your support. I added the code I wrote and the response as an answer. I tried this code but got error.

Comment: @minhhn2910 i found the error. Even if the contract is a transfer, there must be some ETH in the wallet address. thank you very much <3